# By default, an instance gets rebooted when we try to create an AMI from it?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, instance, ubuntu-18.04

When I am trying to backup of ami without a check on reboot option it will automatic rebooted sever (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sir, whenever I am trying to snapshot of my instance without a click on no reboot option, my instance automatically rebooted.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The instance will be rebooted during the creation of an AMI. This is done so that the image is fully saved to disk. (It's like nicely shutting-down a computer vs pulling out the power cord.) If you do _not_ want it to reboot, then select the **No reboot** option.

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you are creating an AMI out of an EC2, AWS shutdowns the VM, then it takes snapshots of all the attached volumes and then creates and registers the AMI. On completion, it powers on the VM. One can choose the No reboot option if you don't want to reboot your instance. However, please note that If you choose No reboot, AWS can't guarantee the file system integrity of the created image.

Refer [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide//tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html)

[image]

Comment: But I never click on No reboot option, but still instance reboot automatically

Comment: "No Reboot" means "Do not reboot". If it is OFF, then the instance _will_ be rebooted.